# How to exclude wildcard directory but include wildcard files using rdiff-backup?

Tags: rsync, glob, rdiff-backup

I am using [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/). Really awesome simple powerful backup tool. However I am fighting with wildcard glob patterns. I have this directory structure:

```
/data/aaa/cache
/data/bbb/cache
/data/ccc/cache
etc....
```

In each cache directory are original files and cache files. Original files are named simply `1.jpg`, `2.png`, `3.gif`, and so on. Cache files have some string attached to the original filename.

So I want to backup all the /data/*/cache directories, but to include only original files, not the cache files.

I am using this command:
`rdiff-backup --exclude **/cache --include **/cache/+([0-9]).+([a-z]) /data /backup`

But rdiff-backup returns this and I am lost:

```
Found interrupted initial backup. Removing...
Fatal Error: Last selection expression:
    Command-line include glob: **/cache/+([0-9]).+([a-z])
only specifies that files be included.  Because the default is to
include all files, the expression is redundant.  Exiting because this
probably isn't what you meant.
```

Comment: Do you want to exclude any *other* files or directories under `/data` that aren't cache directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup.1.html :

```
   A given file is excluded by the file selection system exactly
   when the first matching file selection condition
   specifies that the file be excluded; otherwise the file is included.
```

...

```
   For instance,

          rdiff-backup --include /usr --exclude /usr /usr /backup

   is exactly the same as

          rdiff-backup /usr /backup

   because  the  include  and  exclude  directives  match exactly the same
   files, and the --include comes first, giving it precedence.
```

So, in your case, it is complaining about the final `--include` because if a file gets there (i.e. it isn't matched by the previous `--exclude`) it will be included whether or not it matches the `--include`. That's what the error message was trying to say.

As for how to accomplish your goal...

Assuming you do want to exclude **only** paths of the form: `/data/*/cache/[0-9]*.[a-z][a-z][a-z]?*` just specify that:

```
rdiff-backup --exclude '/data/*/cache/[0-9]*.[a-z][a-z][a-z]?*' --exclude '*' /data /backup
```

This should work (I haven't tested it).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, however I can't use your solution, because my scenario is little bit complicated. I have simplified it for the sake of this question. In my real example, I am backing up more directories so I can't use `--exclude '*'`, because I generally need to include them all, not exclude them all. Hope, if you can modify your answer. Thanks again

Comment: So which files & directories *do* you want to exclude, exactly? Just the cache files?

Comment: Well, here's a possible answer... hope you're still listening.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to do a two step process:

1. create a list of all files you want to exclude e.g. with find . -name "**/cache" > excludes.lst
2. use the list with --exclude-filelist excludes.lst

This way you can avoid fighting with the glob option and you have full control over your excludes